# How to calculate total value from razor view with javascript? MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I got a .Net project using MVC and Razor.
I pass to the view a list containing products, where I have  ProdutoValor( product value) with a TextboxFor for QuantidaVenda (Number os itens sold) for each iten. I want to get the value "QuantidadeVenda * ProdutoValor" for each item and show in a textbox the total value. How can I manage to do that with javascript?

I wanto to calculate the total as soon as the user enters the quantity

here is my view :

```
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Produtos.Count; i++)
            {

                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produtos[i].ProdutoId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produtos[i].ProdutoDescricao)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Produtos[i].ProdutoNome)@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produtos[i].ProdutoNome)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Produtos[i].ProdutoValor, new { @class = "form-control", Value = Model.Produtos[i].ProdutoValor }) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produtos[i].ProdutoValor)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Produtos[i].ProdutoEstoque, new { @class = "form-control", Value = Model.Produtos[i].ProdutoEstoque })@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Produtos[i].ProdutoEstoque)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (Model.Produtos[i].ProdutoEstoque < 1)
                        {
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Produtos[i].QuantidadeVenda, new { value = 0, disabled = "disabled" })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Produtos[i].QuantidadeVenda, new { value = 0, @id = "quantidade" })
                            if (Model.Produtos[i].ProdutoEstoque < Model.Produtos[i].QuantidadeVenda)
                            {<p>valor invalido</p>}
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }

     [enter image description here][1]
```

[how the list looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv7s6.png)

Comment: What you could do is on (whatever box is the last you want to enter data into), add an onblur that calls a simply javascript function which calculates these values. This would only work if the user enters the value in the same order every time. For example, (enter box 1 value) (enter box 2 value `onblur=""`)

Comment: nah.. it won't happen like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Javascript:

```
Onchange Event for  QuantidadeVenda(quantity):
function onchange()
{
var total=  document.getElementById("name of total textbox").Value* 
            document.getElementById("name of quantity textbox").value
  document.getElementById("name of total textbox").innerHTML=total
}
```

Jquery:

```
on change or LostFocus Event
$("input").change(function(){
   var total=  $("#name of total textbox").val()* 
               $("#name of quantity textbox").val()
      $("#name of total textbox").val=total
});
```

***Updated Code***

HTML:

```
<table  border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>product</td>
        <td>quantity</td>
        <td>total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                10
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="" onchange="myFunction(this)">
            </td>
            <td><label>_</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                10
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txt" value="" onchange="myFunction(this)">
            </td>
            <td><label>_</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
 function myFunction($this) {
        debugger           $($this).parent().siblings(":last").find('label').text($($this).parent().siblings().first().text().trim() * $this.value)

    }
```

Comment: but i'll have a list being generated by the "for" loop... how can I bind this item quantity and value like this?

Comment: you mean to say bind  a event ?

Comment: Sorry. wrong word... how can I get the value * quantity for each item in the list like this?   cause If I put an ID on the texbot, every iten will have the same ID on his textbox...

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not very good with javascript yet... I'm getting an error "$ is not defined" ..  trying to handle it..

Comment: add jquery reference to your project , add it  via nuget package

Comment: just add this code to layout cshtml page `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: It works very well man.. Thanks.. I just need one more little tip... the .first(), on my table, is returning the Name of the product.. how do I get the Second?

Comment: $($this).parent().siblings().eq(1).text().trim()) did it... tx man.. you were very helpfull